# Extracting type from a reified, type-checked `Tree` in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Given the following REPL session:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>cm}

scala> val r = reify { val a = 234.45 }
r: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] =
Expr[Unit]({
  val a = 234.45;
  ()
})

scala> val c = cm.mkToolBox().typecheck(r.tree)
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
c: qual$2.u.Tree forSome { val qual$2: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] @scala.reflect.internal.annotations.uncheckedBounds } =
{
  val a: Double = 234.45;
  ()
}
```

What's the recommended way of pulling out the type of variable `a` from the type-checked tree `c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using [quasiquotes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/definition-details.html), but I'm not sure that it's the easiest way to do:

```
scala> val c = cm.mkToolBox().typecheck(r.tree)
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
c: qual$2.u.Tree forSome { val qual$2:     scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type]     @scala.reflect.internal.annotations.uncheckedBounds } =
{
  val a: Double = 234.45;
  ()
}

scala> val q"{val $name: $tpt = $rhs; ()}" = c
name: reflect.runtime.universe.TermName = a
tpt: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Double
rhs: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = 234.45

scala> :t tpt.tpe
reflect.runtime.universe.Type

scala> println(tpt.tpe)
Double
```

Comment: Excellent! It's like quasiquotes are the `unapply` of `reify`.

Comment: More like, what's reify? `val q"val $name: $tpt = $rhs" = currentMirror.mkToolBox().typecheck(q"val a = 234.45")`